# estimate in lm function in R doesn't match correlation (data with NA)

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I'm fitting lm model

```
x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, NA, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4)
y <- c(0.3, 0.2, 0.5, NA, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4)
fit1<-lm(scale(y) ~ scale(x), na.action=na.omit)
summary(fit1)
```

This gives me a standardized estimate -0.593
When I apply the function 'cor' it gives me value of -0.577.
If i subset complete cases from two vectors i.e.

```
x2 <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4)
y2 <- c(0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4)
```

and then fit lm

```
fit2<-lm(scale(y2) ~ scale(x2))
summary(fit2)
```

the standardized estimate is the same as in the case of 'cor'(-0.577). I think standardized estimate and correlation coefficient should be the same in simple regression. The question is what is the problem with fit1? (using 'na.action=na.excluse' is not helpful).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code `scale` is applied prior to `na.omit` within `lm`. Compare these two:

```
DF <- data.frame(x, y) 
na.omit(scale(DF))
scale(na.omit(DF))
```

And then use this:

```
fit1<-lm(scale(y) ~ scale(x), data=na.omit(DF))

all.equal(unname(coef(fit1)[2]),
          cor(na.omit(DF))[1,2])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is not the OP desiring. Statistical the correlation and standardized regression coefficient should be the same. I think OP want to verify this equality.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Thanks for pointing that out. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd never guess myself!